# How to combine lists to create two specific sets of lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure how to write a code that combines given lists into a two lists as specified in the Solution variable shown below. Basically, what is the code that will make me go from

```py
Crosspairs = [1,6], [4,2], [7,10], [3,5], [9,8]
Sharedpairs = [1,4], [3,9], [4,7], [3,7], [2,6], [2,10], [5,8], [10,5]
```

to

```
Solution = [1,4,7,3,9], [6,2,10,5,8]
```

The order of the numbers in each list does not matter. What matters are the values in each list. For example,

```
[1,4,7,3,9]
```

would be just as good as

```
[4,3,7,1,9]
```

Also, the Crosspairs, Sharedpairs, and Solution variables do not all have to be a certain type. They can be a list of lists, a dictionary, or a tuple.

I appreciate all the help and feedback.

EDIT:

I've tried this and it works. There's multiple for loops but it'll do for now unless something better is brought up.

```py
Sharedpairs = [[1,4], [3,9], [4,7], [3,7], [2,6], [2,10], [5,8], [10,5]]

Group1 = Sharedpairs[0]
Sharedpairs.remove(Sharedpairs[0])

for i, p in enumerate(Sharedpairs):
    print(i,p)
    if (p[0] in Group1):
        Group1.append(p[1])
        Sharedpairs.remove(p)
        print('Group 1', Group1)
for i, p in enumerate(Sharedpairs):
    print(i,p)
    if (p[1] in Group1):
        Group1.append(p[0])
        Sharedpairs.remove(p)
        print('Group 1', Group1)
for i, p in enumerate(Sharedpairs):
    print(i,p)
    if (p[0] in Group1):
        Group1.append(p[1])
        Sharedpairs.remove(p)
        print('Group 1', Group1)
    elif (p[1] in Group1):
        Group1.append(p[0])
        Sharedpairs.remove(p)
        print('Group 1', Group1)
    else:
        print('Not in group')
        continue
Group1
[1, 4, 7, 3, 9]
```

Comment: Not sure why the 7 and 10 are interchanged?

Comment: Perhaps you could post your attempt.

Comment: can you explain the logic how , the output for second sharedpair work, first one is get the max, min inn alternate

Comment: @yatu the order of the 7 and 10 list does not matter.

Comment: This is my raw attempt so far: ```python Crosspairs = [1,6], [4,2], [10,7], [3,5], [9,8]
Sharedpairs = [1,9], [3,9], [4,7], [3,7], [2,6], [2,10], [5,8], [10,5]

set1 = []
set2 = []

for i in Crosspairs:
    for j in i:
        if j not in set1:
            for k in Sharedpairs:
                for l in k:
                    if j == l:
                        set1.append(j)
                    else:
                        set2.append(j)
set1

Comment: Can you share the logic ? No logic No solution ..

Comment: Ok. So imgine a 2 row by 5 column table. From left to right starting from the top row, each cell has a single value in the table and they are 1, 4, 7, 3, and 9. From left to right starting from the bottom row, each cell has a single value in the table and they are 6, 2, 10, 5, and 8. The Crosspairs are those values that are in the same column while the Sharedpairs are those values that share the same boundary (i.e. row) in the table.

Comment: @KaiesLAMIRI I hope the logic I described makes sense

Comment: @prashantrana I hope the logic I described makes sense.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I hope the logic I described makes sense

Comment: @yatu I hope the logic I described makes sense

Comment: @bpozo27 don't you think it should be [1,4] not [1,9] in sharedpair list ?

Comment: @prashantrana Yes you are correct thank you for that catch. It should reflect the [1,4] and not [1,9] now correctly.

Comment: Is `Solution` only the result of looking at `Crosspairs` or does it somehow take `Sharedpairs` into account too?

Comment: @Zhenhir it also takes Sharedpairs into account as well. But if Sharedpairs or Crosspairs is the only variable necessary to come up with the Solution variable then that should work. Ideally using both the Sharedpairs and Crosspairs variables to come up with the Solution should be the way to go since we're given both sets of information.

Comment: My point was you can't just post a problem. This isn't a code writing/homework service. You need to edit your post to include your code, and we can help you with errors in your code. We should not post the final solution to the problem until you have put in a solid effort and got stuck. Look into connected components (graph theory).

Comment: Hint: imagine smaller sets that haven't been assigned to side1 or side2 yet. Imagine merging them as you find connections, so they grow like water drops merging into two big puddles.

Comment: Also you said that the input could be a dictionary. What would the structure of that look like? Would the items from the list just be in the values? (Also assuming that would be an `OrderedDict`)

Comment: @Zhenhir For ease  of coding, yes the list items would be in the values with the key perhaps being the row number or row name.

Comment: Ok, updated the code and tested that in my answer..

Answer (score 0):

this is not optimum solution, but it can check if the created rows are correct or not

```
Crosspairs = [[1,6], [4,2], [7,10], [3,5], [9,8]]
Sharedpairs = [[1,4], [3,9], [4,7], [3,7], [2,6], [2,10], [5,8], [10,5]]
# taking rows
l1= [i[0] for i in Crosspairs]
l2=[i[1] for i in Crosspairs]

# creating shared pair
match = [ sorted([l1[i],l1[i+1]])for i in range(len(l1)-1)] + [ sorted([l2[i],l2[i+1]])for i in range(len(l2)-1)] 

# sorting to match whether the created shared pair equal to orignal share pair
# if yes then print the two rows

match.sort(key=lambda x:[x[0],x[1]])

sp2 = [sorted(i) for i in Sharedpairs]
sp2.sort(key=lambda x:[x[0],x[1]])


if sp2 == match:
    print(l1,l2,sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes the order of `Sharedpairs` will always illustrate pairs from row 1 and then pairs from row 2.. You can get the solution from either list this way and just verify that the solutions match. You do need `Crosspairs` to determine the number of rows.. otherwise I guess you'd need to put that in manually.

I took the liberty of using sets since you said order doesn't matter.. and that makes dealing with duplicates in `Sharedpairs` easier.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import defaultdict

Crosspairs = [1,6], [4,2], [7,10], [3,5], [9,8]
Sharedpairs = [1,4], [3,9], [4,7], [3,7], [2,6], [2,10], [5,8], [10,5]
OP_Solution = set([1,4,7,3,9]), set([6,2,10,5,8])

# Allow for dicts (tested).. this assumes ordering the keys will give us
# The rows/columns in the same order as your inputs..
# I think anything fancier than that will require a specific example
# Of a dict input
def convert_dict(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        return [v for k,v in sorted(x.items())]
    return x

Crosspairs = convert_dict(Crosspairs)
Sharedpairs = convert_dict(Sharedpairs)
"""
Representations of data
1, 4, 7,  3, 9
6, 2, 10, 5, 8

1, 6
4, 2
7, 10
3, 5
9, 8
"""

# Get number of rows from Crosspairs
n_rows = len(Crosspairs[0])

# This is all you need to get the result from Crosspairs
Cross_Solution = tuple(set(x) for x in zip(*Crosspairs))

# Create a defaultdict so we can have multiple sets depending
# On what row we're up to.
Shared_Solution = defaultdict(set)
row_n = 0
i = 0
for row in Sharedpairs:
    i += 1
    # If our counter (i) is greater than all our pairs
    # Divided by the number of rows we're up to a new row
    if i > len(Sharedpairs) / n_rows:
        row_n += 1
        i = 1

    # Row 1 will be under Shared_Solution[0]
    for x in row:
        Shared_Solution[row_n].add(x)

Shared_Solution = tuple(Shared_Solution.values())

# All our solutions are the same.. print one of them.. doesn't matter which.
print(OP_Solution == Cross_Solution == Shared_Solution)
print(Cross_Solution)
```

Result:

```
True
({1, 3, 4, 7, 9}, {2, 5, 6, 8, 10})
```

EDIT: Made this deal with `n` rows.. instead of just 2.

If I change things to:

```
Crosspairs = [1,6,1,6], [4,2,2,7], [7,10,3,8], [3,5,4,9], [9,8,5,10]
Sharedpairs = [1,4], [3,9], [4,7], [3,7], [2,6], [2,10], [5,8], [10,5],\
        [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [6,7], [7,8], [8,9], [9,10]
OP_Solution = set([1,4,7,3,9]), set([6,2,10,5,8]), set([1,2,3,4,5]), set([6,7,8,9,10])
```

Result:

```
True
({1, 3, 4, 7, 9}, {2, 5, 6, 8, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10})
```

Also works with dicts now.. tested with this:

```
Crosspairs = {"col1":[1,6,1,6], "col2":[4,2,2,7], "col3":[7,10,3,8], "col4":[3,5,4,9], "col5":[9,8,5,10]}
```

Comment: If we're assuming Crosspairs is the zip, then you may want to use zip(*Crosspairs)

Comment: Still had to put in some ugliness to get a tuple of sets, but good idea.. thank you.